# "The method '[]' was called on null." When calling an API

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using an API from disease.sh in my COVID-19 tracker project and but when I called `worldData ['cases']` in the UI, an error occurred:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("cases")
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'api.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Map worldData;
fetchWorldData() async {
  Response response =
      await get(Uri.parse('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'));
  worldData = json.decode(response.body);
}

Widget coloredCard() => Card(
      shadowColor: Colors.red,
      elevation: 8,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Colors.red[500], Colors.red[500]],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        )),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Comfirmed',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 23,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 4),
            Text(
              worldData['cases'].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I tried to replace `worldData['cases']` with `"123"` and the error disappeared.
If you can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Post the part that is giving you the error, where are you calling  `['cases']`?

Comment: The part that is giving me the error is at line 41: Text(worldData['cases'].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white)

Comment: You api is not responding properly or your are handling the result well. Add  `assert(worldData != null) in fetchUrlData function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchWorldData` function is async. You need to handle the UI according to the result of the async function. In this case you can use `FutureBuilder`.

I've updated your code with FutureBuilder. It will work, but the `FutureBuilder` should be obtained before e.g. in `initState`. Please have a look at the code below also.

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchWorldData() async {
  Response response =
      await get(Uri.parse('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'));
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

Widget coloredCard() => Card(
      shadowColor: Colors.red,
      elevation: 8,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Colors.red[500], Colors.red[500]],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        )),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Comfirmed',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 23,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 4),
            FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
              future: fetchWorldData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(
                    snapshot.data['cases'].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 50,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('there is no data yet');
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The full example with the good point that was mentioned in comment by Problematic Dude.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.

```dart
class FullFutureExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FullFutureExampleState createState() => _FullFutureExampleState();
}

class _FullFutureExampleState extends State<FullFutureExample> {
  Future _covidFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _covidFuture = fetchWorldData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return coloredCard();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchWorldData() async {
    Response response =
        await get(Uri.parse('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Widget coloredCard() => Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red[500], Colors.red[500]],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          )),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Comfirmed',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 23,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: _covidFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text(
                      snapshot.data['cases'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text('there is no data yet');
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not a good solution. Read the first line from the official docs. It clearly says that   `The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.`

Comment: @ProblematicDude good point. The provided code in question didn't include the full page anyway I added simple example.